# How to automatically enable vmware-user on Ubuntu guest?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, Precise Pangolin as guest OS in VMware 8 and I have to enter in Terminal tne vmware-user command each time I want to enable VMware tools (autoresize screen, shared clipboard, VMWARE unity) and I could not figure out a way to have this feature automatically activated. The VMware doc says that's because I don't use a session manager.
Any idea?